# If google tag manager is installed, the scripts of other tools are being downloaded in browser

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, facebook-pixel

We have implemented Google analytics, Facebook pixel and now going to including Google ads remarking script to collect browsing behavior data.

One of our concerns is: probable degradation of site speed due to inclusion of js file of each tool ( Google analytics, Facebook pixel , Google ads remarketing etc. as dependency)

Does Google Tag manager helps in that ? Is including, script of just GTM enough ?

I did run preview of GTM and saw network log of browser, it is downloading analytics.js from google and fbevents.js from facebook. That means collection and relaying of events happen at client side.

Need to confirm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I confirm that they definitely happen on the client side. It deliver the same Javascript scripts on the page (which you can put directly on the page if you don't use Tag Manager).

Comment: However there is now a server-side GTM option, seeing that the OPs problem seems to be load times from downloading all the tracking libraries.

Comment: Yes, GTM server-side is another solution (not free) which may further the issue of loading scripts. In the context of the question the reference seems to the classic client-side GTM.